# Issue of inding text of lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I'm going to find a text on an element tree, but there are two situations that I cannot get the text and it shows 'None'

**First Situation: First tag has a link**

```
from lxml import etree 

node = etree.fromstring("<a xml = 'www.www.com'><c>bum</c></a>")

print node.findtext('c',default = 'what happened?')
```

**Second Situation: Text tag's parent tag has no content**

```
from lxml import etree 

node = etree.fromstring('<a><b><c>bum</c></b></a>')

print node.findtext('c', default = 'what happened?')
```

**Successful Code: No link and tag that has no content**

```
from lxml import etree 

node = etree.fromstring('<a><c>bum</c></a>')

print node.findtext('c')
```

I want to know how can I get text of bum on these two situation

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.iter` to find the correct tag(s), and then `.text`:

```
node1 = etree.fromstring("<a xml = 'www.www.com'><c>bum</c></a>")
node2 = etree.fromstring('<a><b><c>bum</c></b></a>')

for c_node in node1.iter(tag='c'):
    print(c_node.text)
    # bum

for c_node in node2.iter(tag='c'):
    print(c_node.text)
    # bum
```

Note that in the 1st case `print(node1.find('c').text)` works too, but in the 2nd (`print(node2.find('c').text)`) it doesn't.